# Flutter - change list based on variable number

Tags: flutter, dart

This might be a basic question for someone, but is it possible to change the list based on the variable. Example of my code:

```
        if(screen == 1) {
          messages1.add(
            _Message(
              1,
              screen,
              backspacesCounter > 0
                  ? _messageBuffer.substring(
                  0, _messageBuffer.length - backspacesCounter)
                  : _messageBuffer + dataString.substring(0, index),
            ),
          );
        }
```

Now I have 7 lists and I would prefer not to use if-else or switch to check for thee screen variable and based on that adding it to one of those 7 lists.

I am sure there is a much more elegant solution that could look like:

```
messages[screen].add(
            _Message(
              1,
              screen,
              backspacesCounter > 0
                  ? _messageBuffer.substring(
                  0, _messageBuffer.length - backspacesCounter)
                  : _messageBuffer + dataString.substring(0, index),
            ),
          );
```

But how do I go about this? How do I make sure that the list number of `messages1` list will be dynamic based on the variable (int) like `messages[screen]`. I guess this will be simple for someone good at Dart or working with Flutter long enough.
Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: If you could just elaborate a bit more about what you want, it would be helpful.

Comment: @ArshShaikh Can you check this Q? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63620007/flutter-query-snapshot-map-to-list-if-conditional-is-met